# How do I open the search results in a different html page using php

Tags: php, html, json, connection

I have created a small search bar which will generate movie details but I want the results to open in a separate html page can you guys please help me this problem?

My code is below

```
<div class="form-container">

        <form method="POST">
            <div class="search-container">
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit-search">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form> 
        <div class="resutls">
        <?php

            if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {

                $txtresult = $_POST['search'];

                if ($txtresult == 'red') {
                    echo "<span class= 'red'>".$txtresult."</span><br>";
                }elseif ($txtresult == 'green') {
                    echo "<span class= 'green'>".$txtresult."</span><br>";
                }

                function    getImdbRecord($title, $ApiKey)
                    {
                        $path = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=$title&apikey=$ApiKey";
                        $json = file_get_contents($path);
                        return json_decode($json, TRUE);

                    }
                $data = getImdbRecord($txtresult, "f3d054e8");  
                echo "<span class = 'info-box'><h3> Name :".$data['Title']."</h3><h3> Year : ".$data['Year']."</h3><h3> Duration : ".$data['Runtime'],"</h3></span>";

    }

        ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the action parameter in form tag to specify a different HTML/PHP Page.

```
<form action="otherFile.php" method="POST">
```

Then you need to move the code to fetch results to otherFile.php

Answer (score 1):

Add `action` attributes in your form HTML element. The action attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted. No need to write PHP code in this page/file. Example:

```
<div class="form-container">
    <form method="POST" action="searchResult.php">
        <div class="search-container">
           <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit-search">Search</button>
        </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

And write your PHP code in that `searchResult.php` file. Example:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
    $txtresult = $_POST['search'];
    if ($txtresult == 'red') {
        echo "<span class= 'red'>".$txtresult."</span><br>";
    }elseif ($txtresult == 'green') {
        echo "<span class= 'green'>".$txtresult."</span><br>";
    }

    function getImdbRecord($title, $ApiKey)
    {
        $path = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=$title&apikey=$ApiKey";
        $json = file_get_contents($path);
        return json_decode($json, TRUE);
    }

    $data = getImdbRecord($txtresult, "f3d054e8");

    if (isset($data['Error']) && 'Movie not found!' == $data['Error']) {
        echo "<span class= 'red'>{$data['Error']} by keyword <b>{$txtresult}</b></span><br>";
    } else {
        echo "<span class = 'info-box'><h3> Name :".$data['Title']."</h3><h3> Year : ".$data['Year']."</h3><h3> Duration : ".$data['Runtime'],"</h3></span>";
    }
}
```